# Google Script - Attachments to Drive

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script, email-attachments, gmail-api

I have the code below, but i've been struggling to get it to work properly, either it creates duplicate folders every time i run it, or it doesn't upload the attachments and just creates the folders... I am also getting an error now that the newMail Uploads object does not have a .hasnext() function.

What i want to do, is have this script running and it puts attachments in a folder relating to their label  -- So in the code below, all mail with the newMail label would go to a single folder, but i want to be able to extend the code further to run for multiple labels ect, so i want to check if the relevant folders exist and if not create them, if they exist they should be used.

-Edit, Now it is only taking the attachment from the first email from a certain address.

```
    function startProcess()
{
  var gmailLabels  = "newLabel";  
  var driveFolder  = "newFolder";  
  var archiveLabel = "Processed";
  var moveToLabel =  GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(archiveLabel);

   if ( ! moveToLabel )
   {    
    moveToLabel = GmailApp.createLabel(archiveLabel);    
   }

  findFolder(gmailLabels, driveFolder, archiveLabel, moveToLabel);

}

function findFolder(gmailLabels, driveFolder, archiveLabel, moveToLabel)
{
  var filter = "has:attachment label:" + gmailLabels; 


  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveFolder);

  if (folder.hasNext()) {
    folder = folder.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder);
  }

  callThreads(gmailLabels, driveFolder, archiveLabel, moveToLabel, filter, folder)

}

function callThreads(gmailLabels, driveFolder, archiveLabel, moveToLabel, filter, folder)
{
  var threads = GmailApp.search(filter); 
for (var x=0; x<threads.length; x++) {
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels);
    var message = threads[x].getMessages()[x];

    var desc   = message.getSubject() + " #" + message.getId();
    var att    = message.getAttachments();

    for (var z=0; z<att.length; z++) {
      try {
        file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
        file.setDescription(desc);
      }
      catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
      }
    }

    //threads[x].addLabel(moveToLabel); 
    label.removeFromThreads(threads);
    //threads[x].moveToTrash();
  }

}
```

Comment: It looks like *step one* is:  If a folder that you want doesn't exist, then create it.  I'd put that into it's own function.  Right now you have lots of different processes all in one function.

Comment: Hi, your logic seems a little backward. Shouldn't you rather loop through your mails/email threads, then do your file handling and directory checking.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not differentiating between a Thread and Single Message. I think it's treating the entire thread as the message.

I don't see how we can do that though?

I thought perhaps moving it to trash, but that didn't solve anything, and I can't find a way to purge the trash immediately after moving.

Comment: A thread is just a collection of messages. So when you call `getMessages();` it returns an array of messages. However, `threads[x].getMessages()[x]` you keep calling it on the same index. So for thread[1] (that contains say 30 messages you will return the first message of that thread). For thread[2] you will accept the 2nd message in that email thread. Is this desired behavior? Shouldn't you be looping through your mails within a thread as well?

Comment: and invoke `getAttachments()` on each mail. Then do some validation and checking on that attachment.

Comment: Thanks, feel like an idiot for missing that. However i noticed that labels seem to be thread specific, so it still did the same, but staring a message is message specific, so i did a second round of checks based on the star, and now it works. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion.  I haven't tested this code, it probably doesn't work.  But that's not the point.  I'm trying to show how you might create some order to your code so that it's easier to understand and debug:

```
function sendToGoogleDrive() {
  makeNewFolders();
  putEmailsIntoFolders();
};


function makeNewFolders() {
  var gmailLabels  = "newMail";  
  var driveFolder  = "newMail";  
  var archiveLabel = "Processed";

  var rootUploadFolders ="newMail Uploads";
  var rootDriveFolder = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var rootExist = false;
  var childExist = false;

  while (rootDriveFolder.hasNext()) {
    var folder = rootDriveFolder.next();
    if(folder.getName()==rootUploadFolders) {
      var folderId = folder.getId();

      if(folder.getName()!==driveFolder) {
        var child = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFolder(driveFolder);
      };

    };
  };
};

function putEmailsIntoFolders() {

};
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i know it was a little messy, that was a little out of frustration.

I have made it a little neater.

Currently, i am encountering the problems that:

Either it uploads attachments from a previous email (if there are more than 1 from the same address) Or it simply does nothing.